# i18next - Providing a key in data-i18n-options attribute for interpolation

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

Currently using i18next.js and have run in to a problem.

Say there's two keys:

```
{
    'keyOne':'I am __name__',
    'item': 'a person'
}
```

In the html:

```
<div data-i18n="keyOne" data-i18n-options={"name":"item"}></div>
```

And the result I'd like:

'I am a person'

Where 'a person' isn't the string literal but the reference to the key (i.e. like using data-i18n attribute)

Would it be possible to provide the 'item' key (not the string 'a person') for use in 'keyOne' for interpolation? This would be useful as when I change the locale I'd only have to call .i18n() on the div and both keys would be translated. Without this functionality I'd have to re-evaluate the context and update the div manually.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i18next has *nesting* functionality: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/nesting

So I could make what you want. You can test in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/leonardonsantos/3zy4xmnm/1/

Just change in `data-i18n-options` with this `$t`:

```
<div data-i18n="keyOne" data-i18n-options='{"name":"$t(item)"}'>
```